# How long does it take for Google Analytics Goals to start show some data?

Tags: web-development, google-analytics

I am testing Google Analytics Goals but I am not sure if I have it setup correctly. I setup a basic 3 step goal just as a test. I then went to my web site and performed those three steps. Should that immediately show up in Google Analytics under the Goal reports or does it take a few days?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should be less at most 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

24 hrs after you set up an effective goal that is properly matched to the traffic you are trying to match and monitor.

If your rule set doesn't match any of your traffic, never.

Comment: Thanks! I wish there is a way to make it real time for testing purposes.